# Laravel get internal server error(500) on CentOS

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, centos, web-deployment

During deploy laravel project on Centos, I have gotten this error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/html/<laravel_project_name>/config/database.php on line 16
```

I have enabled pdo extension with editing php.ini file.

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

Please help me to fix this error.
Regards.

Comment: Have you checked the error log? There should be some good stuff there.

Comment: Check file name capital and small letter LIKE "A" "a" both diferent on  CentOS. Of FILE

Comment: I agree with Alex, first check your PHP error log. That being said, I have encountered this error before when I did not chmod my storage folder. Check the folder's permissions.

Comment: Thanks Alex.
I have check php error log and I can get idea.
But there is error PDO not found, can u help me more?

Comment: after editing the php.ini file did you restart apache (or your http server)?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted httpd server.
I did like this:

service httpd restart

Comment: Also check if pdo is loaded. Do a $ php -m and verify that pdo and pdo_mysql are on the displayed list